# Which one is right? "Last talk" or "last talked"?

Tags: difference

Which one is right?

> Do you remember when we last talk?

or

> Do you remember when we last talked?

Comment: Don't be misled by Present Tense *Do you remember*. Think of a different context, such as *When we last **talked**, you were very polite*.

Comment: The second is correct, because it uses a past tense.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is correct.

**Do you remember when...?** is a question that asks the person if they *currently* remember something from the *past*. So, naturally, we use the past tense for the phrase following the question.

> Do you remember when **we last talked**?

If you were to take the second part of the sentence and turn it into a statement, you would say something like this:

> We last **talked** yesterday.

and not:

> We last **talk** yesterday.

So we use the past tense to ask if the person remembers what **had** happened.